# PDAL: Unable to open stream for ' '

Tags: pdal, laz, pipeline

I tried to run a batch process for pdal pipeline, however I always get a en error:

> PDAL: Unable to open stream

Below is the pipeline and the batch code:

```
{
    "pipeline": [
        {"type":"readers.las"
        },
        {
            "type": "filters.range",
            "limits": "Classification[2:2]"
        },
        {
            "gdaldriver": "GTiff",
            "output_type": "mean",
            "resolution": 1,
            "type": "writers.gdal"
        }
    ]
}
```

following is the PowerShell code:

```
$files = Get-ChildIdtem 'D:/nicola/2021_a2q/*.laz'
foreach ($f in $files) {
pdal pipeline 'C:/Users/dpuhl/Documents/nicola/pipeline_batch.json' 
--reader.las.filename='D:/nicola/2021_a2q/$f($f_.BaseName).laz'
--writer.gdal.filename='D:/nicola/output_2021_a2q/dem2/$f($f_.BaseName).tif'
}
```

Error message:

> PDAL: Unable to open stream for ' ' with error 'No error'

As the error message tells 'No error' I'm really unsure what to do.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to enclose your pipeline in brackets "[ ]" to make it a list?